# Unable to do marginLeft:0 to a particular component inside the Body in Next Js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, frontend

This is what my `layout.js` looks like:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
 return (
 <html lang="en">
  <body className={inter.className} style={{ marginRight: '0px' }}>{children}</body>
 </html>
 )
}
```

Now my Body has default margin:8px, but as you can see that I have made marginRight = 0 and now I want only my footer to have marginLeft = 0.

This is how my `page.js` looks like:

```
const page = () => {
return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
     <Navbar />
     <About />
     <Reasons />
     <LatestArticles />
     <Footer/>
   </div>
 )
}
```

Also my `page.module.css` is empty.

Now what I have tried:

```
const page = () => {
 return (
   <div className={styles.container}>
     <Navbar />
     <About />
     <Reasons />
     <LatestArticles />
     <Footer style={{marginLeft: '0px'}}/>
  </div>
 )
}
```

or inside my footer component (`Footer.jsx` file):

```
const Footer = () => {
  return (
   <div className={styles.container} style={{marginLeft: '0px'}}>
    {Footer content}
   </div>
```

None of this worked and I have no idea how to do it, any way anyone can help will be hugely appreciated .

Comment: From react viewpoint, you don't use `marginRight: '0'`, it is either `marginRight: 0` or `marginRight: '0px'`, I'd suggest just using numbers and leave the unit out if you don't need to specify, it always fallbacks to px

Comment: @juxhinbleta thank you for mentioning, But somehow it was doing the job so i didn't notice it （*＾-＾*）